# Why is my animation in Squarespace working in Chrome but not on Safari?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, squarespace

I added a typewriter animation to my Squarespace site using a Code Block and HTML code. It works on Google Chrome, but not on Safari. I read that 'transform' requires extra code to work in Squarespace, but I did not use that function. I've tried reading on the forums on how to solve this but never found.
What could I do differently? If anyone has a link to how someone has solved this before, that would be helpful.

Also, if you have any suggestions on how to improve the code, I would appreciate it as I am a beginning web designer.

```css
.typewriter {
  align-items: center;

  font-size: 350%;
  font-family: "DIN Bold", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.typewriter:after {
  content: " " ;

  color: #ea746a;

  animation: write 15s infinite linear;

  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes write {
  1% {
    content: "A";
  }
  2% {
    content: "AE";
  }
  3% {
    content: "AES";
  }
  4% {
    content: "AEST";
  }
  5% {
    content: "AESTH";
  }
  6% {
    content: "AESTHE";
  }
  7% {
    content: "AESTHET";
  }
  8% {
    content: "AESTHETI";
  }
  9% {
    content: "AESTHETIC";
  }
  10% {
    content: "AESTHETICS";
  }
  11% {
    content: "AESTHETICS.";
  }
  14% {
    content: "AESTHETICS";
  }
  14.5% {
    content: "AESTHETIC";
  }
  15% {
    content: "AESTHETI";
  }
  15.5% {
    content: "AESTHET";
  }
  16% {
    content: "AESTHE";
  }
  16.5% {
    content: "AESTH";
  }
  17% {
    content: "AEST";
  }
  17.5% {
    content: "AES";
  }
  18% {
    content: "AE";
  }
  18.5% {
    content: "A";
  }
  19% {
    content: "";
  }
  20% {
    content: "D";
  }
  21% {
    content: "DI";
  }
  22% {
    content: "DIG";
  }
  23% {
    content: "DIGI";
  }
  24% {
    content: "DIGIT";
  }
  25% {
    content: "DIGITA";
  }
  26% {
    content: "DIGITAL";
  }
  27% {
    content: "DIGITAL M";
  }
  28% {
    content: "DIGITAL M";
  }
  29% {
    content: "DIGITAL MA";
  }
  30% {
    content: "DIGITAL MAR";
  }
  31% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARK";
  }
  32% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARKE";
  }
  33% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARKET";
  }
  34% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARKETI";
  }
  35% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARKETIN";
  }
  36% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARKETING";
  }
  37% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARKETING.";
  }
  39% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARKETING";
  }
  39.5% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARKETIN";
  }
  40% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARKETI";
  }
  40.5% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARKET";
  }
  41% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARKE";
  }
  41.5% {
    content: "DIGITAL MARK";
  }
  42% {
    content: "DIGITAL MAR";
  }
  42.5% {
    content: "DIGITAL MA";
  }
  43% {
    content: "DIGITAL M";
  }
  43.5% {
    content: "DIGITAL";
  }
  44% {
    content: "DIGITA";
  }
  44.5% {
    content: "DIGIT";
  }
  45% {
    content: "DIGI";
  }
  45.5% {
    content: "DIG";
  }
  46% {
    content: "DI";
  }
  46.5% {
    content: "D";
  }
  47% {
    content: "";
  }
  48% {
    content: "C";
  }
  49% {
    content: "CO";
  }
  50% {
    content: "CON";
  }
  51% {
    content: "CONT";
  }
  52% {
    content: "CONTE";
  }
  53% {
    content: "CONTEN";
  }
  54% {
    content: "CONTENT";
  }
  55% {
    content: "CONTENT ";
  }
  56% {
    content: "CONTENT C";
  }
  57% {
    content: "CONTENT CR";
  }
  58% {
    content: "CONTENT CRE";
  }
  59% {
    content: "CONTENT CREA";
  }
  60% {
    content: "CONTENT CREAT";
  }
  61% {
    content: "CONTENT CREATI";
  }
  62% {
    content: "CONTENT CREATIO";
  }
  63% {
    content: "CONTENT CREATION";
  }
  64% {
    content: "CONTENT CREATION.";
  }
  66% {
    content: "CONTENT CREATION";
  }
  66.5% {
    content: "CONTENT CREATIO";
  }
  67% {
    content: "CONTENT CREATI";
  }
  67.5% {
    content: "CONTENT CREAT";
  }
  68% {
    content: "CONTENT CREA";
  }
  68.5% {
    content: "CONTENT CRE";
  }
  69% {
    content: "CONTENT CR";
  }
  69.5% {
    content: "CONTENT ";
  }
  70% {
    content: "CONTENT";
  }
  70.5% {
    content: "CONTEN";
  }
  71% {
    content: "CONTE";
  }
  71.5% {
    content: "CONT";
  }
  72% {
    content: "CON";
  }
  72.5% {
    content: "CO";
  }
  73% {
    content: "C";
  }
  73.5% {
    content: "";
  }
  75% {
    content: "W";
  }
  76% {
    content: "WE";
  }
  77% {
    content: "WEB";
  }
  78% {
    content: "WEB ";
  }
  79% {
    content: "WEB D";
  }
  80% {
    content: "WEB DE";
  }
  81% {
    content: "WEB DES";
  }
  82% {
    content: "WEB DESI";
  }
  83% {
    content: "WEB DESIG";
  }
  84% {
    content: "WEB DESIGN";
  }
  85% {
    content: "WEB DESIGN.";
  }
  86% {
    content: "WEB DESIGN";
  }
  86.5% {
    content: "WEB DESIG";
  }
  87% {
    content: "WEB DESI";
  }
  87.5% {
    content: "WEB DES";
  }
  88% {
    content: "WEB DE";
  }
  88.5% {
    content: "WEB D";
  }
  89% {
    content: "WEB ";
  }
  89.5% {
    content: "WEB";
  }
  90% {
    content: "WE";
  }
  90.5% {
    content: "W";
  }
  91% {
    content: " ";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  TRANSFORM YOUR BRAND THROUGH
  <span>
    <br />
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Likely safari doesn't support some of your css.

Comment: Are you happy to alter your html slightly? If so we can probably do it without needing Javascript by animating something other than content so Safari will be happy.

Comment: problem is safari ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Safari does not currently allow animation of content in pseudo elements so the typewriter-like banner was not moving.

It is possible to get the effect of a typewriter (one character appearing at a time) without using Javascript. It's horrible to do with a non-typewriter font (i.e. if the font isn't fixed width) and even with a typewritery fixed-width font it needs some calculations.

Here is a way of doing it with a typewriter font. The only HTML I changed was to make your span into a div and I gave it a class just as a way of making sure it doesn't interfere with anything else you might have.

We use the before and after pseudo elements on this div to write the banner and to hide those characters we don't want to see. So there are two animations, write on the after pseudo element and writebefore on the before pseudo element. It is arranged like this:

[image]

The green is the before pseudo element which is in front of the banner characters and moves backwards and forward to reveal/hide characters. The red is the after pseudo element which expands and shrinks and moves left and right and has overflow-x hidden. The blue is the div itself.

The keyframes are large - and I used code to create them, fairly simple but in a real world use I guess one would have the code (in JS or PHP or some other scripting language) at run time so it's easy to change the contents of the banner without going through the pain of recalculation. Happy to share that code if required.

```css
div.typewriter {
  position: relative;
  font-size:350%;
  font-family:'DIN Bold',serif;
  align-items:center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom:2em;
  width: 100%;
}

div.typewriterinner {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #ea746a;
  }
  
div.typewriterinner:before, div.typewriterinner:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  animation: write 15s infinite linear;
  background-color: white;
  }
  
div.typewriterinner:before {
  content: ' ';
  animation-name: writebefore;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1em;
  z-index: 2;
  }
  
div.typewriterinner:after {
  content: 'AESTHETICS.CONTENT CREATION.DIGITAL MARKETING.WEB DESIGN.';
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
} 
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  div.typewriterinner:before, div.typewriterinner:after {
    font-size: 6vw; /* just to get one one line - this needs more thought - what do we want to happen? */
  }
}
@keyframes writebefore {0% { margin-left: -0ch;}0.01% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}0.8771929824561403% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}0.8871929824561403% { margin-left: -1ch;}1.7543859649122806% { margin-left: -1ch;}1.7643859649122806% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}2.631578947368421% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}2.6415789473684206% { margin-left: -2ch;}3.508771929824561% { margin-left: -2ch;}3.518771929824561% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}4.385964912280701% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}4.395964912280701% { margin-left: -3ch;}5.263157894736842% { margin-left: -3ch;}5.273157894736841% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}6.140350877192982% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}6.150350877192982% { margin-left: -4ch;}7.017543859649122% { margin-left: -4ch;}7.027543859649122% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}7.894736842105263% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}7.904736842105263% { margin-left: -5ch;}8.771929824561402% { margin-left: -5ch;}8.781929824561402% { margin-left: -5ch;}9.649122807017543% { margin-left: -5ch;}9.659122807017543% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}10.526315789473683% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}10.536315789473683% { margin-left: -4ch;}11.403508771929824% { margin-left: -4ch;}11.413508771929823% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}12.280701754385964% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}12.290701754385964% { margin-left: -3ch;}13.157894736842104% { margin-left: -3ch;}13.167894736842104% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}14.035087719298245% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}14.045087719298245% { margin-left: -2ch;}14.912280701754385% { margin-left: -2ch;}14.922280701754385% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}15.789473684210526% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}15.799473684210525% { margin-left: -1ch;}16.666666666666664% { margin-left: -1ch;}16.676666666666666% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}17.543859649122805% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}17.553859649122806% { margin-left: -0ch;}18.421052631578945% { margin-left: -0ch;}18.431052631578947% { margin-left: --0.5ch;}19.298245614035086% { margin-left: -0ch;}19.308245614035087% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}20.175438596491226% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}20.185438596491228% { margin-left: -1ch;}21.052631578947366% { margin-left: -1ch;}21.062631578947368% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}21.929824561403507% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}21.93982456140351% { margin-left: -2ch;}22.807017543859647% { margin-left: -2ch;}22.81701754385965% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}23.684210526315788% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}23.69421052631579% { margin-left: -3ch;}24.561403508771928% { margin-left: -3ch;}24.57140350877193% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}25.43859649122807% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}25.44859649122807% { margin-left: -4ch;}26.31578947368421% { margin-left: -4ch;}26.32578947368421% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}27.19298245614035% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}27.20298245614035% { margin-left: -5ch;}28.07017543859649% { margin-left: -5ch;}28.08017543859649% { margin-left: -5.5ch;}28.94736842105263% { margin-left: -5.5ch;}28.95736842105263% { margin-left: -6ch;}29.82456140350877% { margin-left: -6ch;}29.834561403508772% { margin-left: -6.5ch;}30.70175438596491% { margin-left: -6.5ch;}30.711754385964912% { margin-left: -7ch;}31.57894736842105% { margin-left: -7ch;}31.588947368421053% { margin-left: -7.5ch;}32.45614035087719% { margin-left: -7.5ch;}32.46614035087719% { margin-left: -8ch;}33.33333333333333% { margin-left: -8ch;}33.34333333333333% { margin-left: -8ch;}34.21052631578947% { margin-left: -8ch;}34.22052631578947% { margin-left: -7.5ch;}35.08771929824561% { margin-left: -7.5ch;}35.09771929824561% { margin-left: -7ch;}35.96491228070175% { margin-left: -7ch;}35.97491228070175% { margin-left: -6.5ch;}36.84210526315789% { margin-left: -6.5ch;}36.85210526315789% { margin-left: -6ch;}37.719298245614034% { margin-left: -6ch;}37.72929824561403% { margin-left: -5.5ch;}38.59649122807017% { margin-left: -5.5ch;}38.60649122807017% { margin-left: -5ch;}39.473684210526315% { margin-left: -5ch;}39.48368421052631% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}40.35087719298245% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}40.36087719298245% { margin-left: -4ch;}41.228070175438596% { margin-left: -4ch;}41.238070175438594% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}42.10526315789473% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}42.11526315789473% { margin-left: -3ch;}42.98245614035088% { margin-left: -3ch;}42.992456140350875% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}43.859649122807014% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}43.86964912280701% { margin-left: -2ch;}44.73684210526316% { margin-left: -2ch;}44.746842105263156% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}45.614035087719294% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}45.62403508771929% { margin-left: -1ch;}46.49122807017544% { margin-left: -1ch;}46.501228070175436% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}47.368421052631575% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}47.37842105263157% { margin-left: -0ch;}48.24561403508772% { margin-left: -0ch;}48.25561403508772% { margin-left: --0.5ch;}49.122807017543856% { margin-left: -0ch;}49.132807017543854% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}50% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}50.01% { margin-left: -1ch;}50.87719298245614% { margin-left: -1ch;}50.887192982456135% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}51.75438596491228% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}51.76438596491228% { margin-left: -2ch;}52.63157894736842% { margin-left: -2ch;}52.641578947368416% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}53.50877192982456% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}53.51877192982456% { margin-left: -3ch;}54.3859649122807% { margin-left: -3ch;}54.3959649122807% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}55.26315789473684% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}55.27315789473684% { margin-left: -4ch;}56.14035087719298% { margin-left: -4ch;}56.15035087719298% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}57.017543859649116% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}57.027543859649114% { margin-left: -5ch;}57.89473684210526% { margin-left: -5ch;}57.90473684210526% { margin-left: -5.5ch;}58.7719298245614% { margin-left: -5.5ch;}58.781929824561395% { margin-left: -6ch;}59.64912280701754% { margin-left: -6ch;}59.65912280701754% { margin-left: -6.5ch;}60.52631578947368% { margin-left: -6.5ch;}60.536315789473676% { margin-left: -7ch;}61.40350877192982% { margin-left: -7ch;}61.41350877192982% { margin-left: -7.5ch;}62.28070175438596% { margin-left: -7.5ch;}62.29070175438596% { margin-left: -8ch;}63.1578947368421% { margin-left: -8ch;}63.1678947368421% { margin-left: -8.5ch;}64.03508771929825% { margin-left: -8.5ch;}64.04508771929825% { margin-left: -8.5ch;}64.91228070175438% { margin-left: -8.5ch;}64.92228070175439% { margin-left: -8ch;}65.78947368421052% { margin-left: -8ch;}65.79947368421053% { margin-left: -7.5ch;}66.66666666666666% { margin-left: -7.5ch;}66.67666666666666% { margin-left: -7ch;}67.54385964912281% { margin-left: -7ch;}67.55385964912281% { margin-left: -6.5ch;}68.42105263157895% { margin-left: -6.5ch;}68.43105263157895% { margin-left: -6ch;}69.29824561403508% { margin-left: -6ch;}69.30824561403509% { margin-left: -5.5ch;}70.17543859649122% { margin-left: -5.5ch;}70.18543859649122% { margin-left: -5ch;}71.05263157894737% { margin-left: -5ch;}71.06263157894738% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}71.9298245614035% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}71.93982456140351% { margin-left: -4ch;}72.80701754385964% { margin-left: -4ch;}72.81701754385965% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}73.68421052631578% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}73.69421052631579% { margin-left: -3ch;}74.56140350877193% { margin-left: -3ch;}74.57140350877194% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}75.43859649122807% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}75.44859649122807% { margin-left: -2ch;}76.3157894736842% { margin-left: -2ch;}76.32578947368421% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}77.19298245614034% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}77.20298245614035% { margin-left: -1ch;}78.0701754385965% { margin-left: -1ch;}78.0801754385965% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}78.94736842105263% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}78.95736842105264% { margin-left: -0ch;}79.82456140350877% { margin-left: -0ch;}79.83456140350877% { margin-left: --0.5ch;}80.7017543859649% { margin-left: -0ch;}80.71175438596491% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}81.57894736842105% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}81.58894736842106% { margin-left: -1ch;}82.45614035087719% { margin-left: -1ch;}82.4661403508772% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}83.33333333333333% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}83.34333333333333% { margin-left: -2ch;}84.21052631578947% { margin-left: -2ch;}84.22052631578947% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}85.0877192982456% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}85.09771929824561% { margin-left: -3ch;}85.96491228070175% { margin-left: -3ch;}85.97491228070176% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}86.84210526315789% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}86.8521052631579% { margin-left: -4ch;}87.71929824561403% { margin-left: -4ch;}87.72929824561403% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}88.59649122807016% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}88.60649122807017% { margin-left: -5ch;}89.47368421052632% { margin-left: -5ch;}89.48368421052632% { margin-left: -5ch;}90.35087719298245% { margin-left: -5ch;}90.36087719298246% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}91.22807017543859% { margin-left: -4.5ch;}91.2380701754386% { margin-left: -4ch;}92.10526315789473% { margin-left: -4ch;}92.11526315789473% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}92.98245614035088% { margin-left: -3.5ch;}92.99245614035088% { margin-left: -3ch;}93.85964912280701% { margin-left: -3ch;}93.86964912280702% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}94.73684210526315% { margin-left: -2.5ch;}94.74684210526316% { margin-left: -2ch;}95.61403508771929% { margin-left: -2ch;}95.62403508771929% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}96.49122807017544% { margin-left: -1.5ch;}96.50122807017544% { margin-left: -1ch;}97.36842105263158% { margin-left: -1ch;}97.37842105263158% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}98.24561403508771% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}98.25561403508772% { margin-left: -0ch;}99.12280701754385% { margin-left: -0ch;}99.13280701754385% { margin-left: -0.5ch;}}@keyframes write {0% { width: 0ch; opacity: 1;}0.01% { width: 1ch; opacity: 1;}0.8771929824561403% { width: 1ch; opacity: 1;}0.8871929824561403% { width: 2ch; opacity: 1;}1.7543859649122806% { width: 2ch; opacity: 1;}1.7643859649122806% { width: 3ch; opacity: 1;}2.631578947368421% { width: 3ch; opacity: 1;}2.6415789473684206% { width: 4ch; opacity: 1;}3.508771929824561% { width: 4ch; opacity: 1;}3.518771929824561% { width: 5ch; opacity: 1;}4.385964912280701% { width: 5ch; opacity: 1;}4.395964912280701% { width: 6ch; opacity: 1;}5.263157894736842% { width: 6ch; opacity: 1;}5.273157894736841% { width: 7ch; opacity: 1;}6.140350877192982% { width: 7ch; opacity: 1;}6.150350877192982% { width: 8ch; opacity: 1;}7.017543859649122% { width: 8ch; opacity: 1;}7.027543859649122% { width: 9ch; opacity: 1;}7.894736842105263% { width: 9ch; opacity: 1;}7.904736842105263% { width: 10ch; opacity: 1;}8.771929824561402% { width: 10ch; opacity: 1;}8.781929824561402% { width: 10ch; opacity: 1;}9.649122807017543% { width: 10ch; margin-left: -0ch;}9.659122807017543% { width: 9ch; margin-left: -0ch; opacity: 1;}10.526315789473683% { width: 9ch; margin-left: -0ch;}10.536315789473683% { width: 8ch; margin-left: -0ch; opacity: 1;}11.403508771929824% { width: 8ch; margin-left: -0ch;}11.413508771929823% { width: 7ch; margin-left: -0ch; opacity: 1;}12.280701754385964% { width: 7ch; margin-left: -0ch;}12.290701754385964% { width: 6ch; margin-left: -0ch; opacity: 1;}13.157894736842104% { width: 6ch; margin-left: -0ch;}13.167894736842104% { width: 5ch; margin-left: -0ch; opacity: 1;}14.035087719298245% { width: 5ch; margin-left: -0ch;}14.045087719298245% { width: 4ch; margin-left: -0ch; opacity: 1;}14.912280701754385% { width: 4ch; margin-left: -0ch;}14.922280701754385% { width: 3ch; margin-left: -0ch; opacity: 1;}15.789473684210526% { width: 3ch; margin-left: -0ch;}15.799473684210525% { width: 2ch; margin-left: -0ch; opacity: 1;}16.666666666666664% { width: 2ch; margin-left: -0ch;}16.676666666666666% { width: 1ch; margin-left: -0ch; opacity: 1;}17.543859649122805% { width: 1ch; margin-left: -0ch;}17.553859649122806% { width: 0ch; margin-left: -0ch; opacity: 1;}18.421052631578945% { width: 0ch; margin-left: -0ch;}18.431052631578947% { width: 10ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}19.298245614035086% { width: 11ch; opacity: 1;}19.308245614035087% { width: 12ch; opacity: 1;}20.175438596491226% { width: 12ch; opacity: 1;}20.185438596491228% { width: 13ch; opacity: 1;}21.052631578947366% { width: 13ch; opacity: 1;}21.062631578947368% { width: 14ch; opacity: 1;}21.929824561403507% { width: 14ch; opacity: 1;}21.93982456140351% { width: 15ch; opacity: 1;}22.807017543859647% { width: 15ch; opacity: 1;}22.81701754385965% { width: 16ch; opacity: 1;}23.684210526315788% { width: 16ch; opacity: 1;}23.69421052631579% { width: 17ch; opacity: 1;}24.561403508771928% { width: 17ch; opacity: 1;}24.57140350877193% { width: 18ch; opacity: 1;}25.43859649122807% { width: 18ch; opacity: 1;}25.44859649122807% { width: 19ch; opacity: 1;}26.31578947368421% { width: 19ch; opacity: 1;}26.32578947368421% { width: 20ch; opacity: 1;}27.19298245614035% { width: 20ch; opacity: 1;}27.20298245614035% { width: 21ch; opacity: 1;}28.07017543859649% { width: 21ch; opacity: 1;}28.08017543859649% { width: 22ch; opacity: 1;}28.94736842105263% { width: 22ch; opacity: 1;}28.95736842105263% { width: 23ch; opacity: 1;}29.82456140350877% { width: 23ch; opacity: 1;}29.834561403508772% { width: 24ch; opacity: 1;}30.70175438596491% { width: 24ch; opacity: 1;}30.711754385964912% { width: 25ch; opacity: 1;}31.57894736842105% { width: 25ch; opacity: 1;}31.588947368421053% { width: 26ch; opacity: 1;}32.45614035087719% { width: 26ch; opacity: 1;}32.46614035087719% { width: 27ch; opacity: 1;}33.33333333333333% { width: 27ch; opacity: 1;}33.34333333333333% { width: 27ch; opacity: 1;}34.21052631578947% { width: 27ch; margin-left: -11ch;}34.22052631578947% { width: 26ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}35.08771929824561% { width: 26ch; margin-left: -11ch;}35.09771929824561% { width: 25ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}35.96491228070175% { width: 25ch; margin-left: -11ch;}35.97491228070175% { width: 24ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}36.84210526315789% { width: 24ch; margin-left: -11ch;}36.85210526315789% { width: 23ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}37.719298245614034% { width: 23ch; margin-left: -11ch;}37.72929824561403% { width: 22ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}38.59649122807017% { width: 22ch; margin-left: -11ch;}38.60649122807017% { width: 21ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}39.473684210526315% { width: 21ch; margin-left: -11ch;}39.48368421052631% { width: 20ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}40.35087719298245% { width: 20ch; margin-left: -11ch;}40.36087719298245% { width: 19ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}41.228070175438596% { width: 19ch; margin-left: -11ch;}41.238070175438594% { width: 18ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}42.10526315789473% { width: 18ch; margin-left: -11ch;}42.11526315789473% { width: 17ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}42.98245614035088% { width: 17ch; margin-left: -11ch;}42.992456140350875% { width: 16ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}43.859649122807014% { width: 16ch; margin-left: -11ch;}43.86964912280701% { width: 15ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}44.73684210526316% { width: 15ch; margin-left: -11ch;}44.746842105263156% { width: 14ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}45.614035087719294% { width: 14ch; margin-left: -11ch;}45.62403508771929% { width: 13ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}46.49122807017544% { width: 13ch; margin-left: -11ch;}46.501228070175436% { width: 12ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}47.368421052631575% { width: 12ch; margin-left: -11ch;}47.37842105263157% { width: 11ch; margin-left: -11ch; opacity: 1;}48.24561403508772% { width: 11ch; margin-left: -11ch;}48.25561403508772% { width: 27ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}49.122807017543856% { width: 28ch; opacity: 1;}49.132807017543854% { width: 29ch; opacity: 1;}50% { width: 29ch; opacity: 1;}50.01% { width: 30ch; opacity: 1;}50.87719298245614% { width: 30ch; opacity: 1;}50.887192982456135% { width: 31ch; opacity: 1;}51.75438596491228% { width: 31ch; opacity: 1;}51.76438596491228% { width: 32ch; opacity: 1;}52.63157894736842% { width: 32ch; opacity: 1;}52.641578947368416% { width: 33ch; opacity: 1;}53.50877192982456% { width: 33ch; opacity: 1;}53.51877192982456% { width: 34ch; opacity: 1;}54.3859649122807% { width: 34ch; opacity: 1;}54.3959649122807% { width: 35ch; opacity: 1;}55.26315789473684% { width: 35ch; opacity: 1;}55.27315789473684% { width: 36ch; opacity: 1;}56.14035087719298% { width: 36ch; opacity: 1;}56.15035087719298% { width: 37ch; opacity: 1;}57.017543859649116% { width: 37ch; opacity: 1;}57.027543859649114% { width: 38ch; opacity: 1;}57.89473684210526% { width: 38ch; opacity: 1;}57.90473684210526% { width: 39ch; opacity: 1;}58.7719298245614% { width: 39ch; opacity: 1;}58.781929824561395% { width: 40ch; opacity: 1;}59.64912280701754% { width: 40ch; opacity: 1;}59.65912280701754% { width: 41ch; opacity: 1;}60.52631578947368% { width: 41ch; opacity: 1;}60.536315789473676% { width: 42ch; opacity: 1;}61.40350877192982% { width: 42ch; opacity: 1;}61.41350877192982% { width: 43ch; opacity: 1;}62.28070175438596% { width: 43ch; opacity: 1;}62.29070175438596% { width: 44ch; opacity: 1;}63.1578947368421% { width: 44ch; opacity: 1;}63.1678947368421% { width: 45ch; opacity: 1;}64.03508771929825% { width: 45ch; opacity: 1;}64.04508771929825% { width: 45ch; opacity: 1;}64.91228070175438% { width: 45ch; margin-left: -28ch;}64.92228070175439% { width: 44ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}65.78947368421052% { width: 44ch; margin-left: -28ch;}65.79947368421053% { width: 43ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}66.66666666666666% { width: 43ch; margin-left: -28ch;}66.67666666666666% { width: 42ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}67.54385964912281% { width: 42ch; margin-left: -28ch;}67.55385964912281% { width: 41ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}68.42105263157895% { width: 41ch; margin-left: -28ch;}68.43105263157895% { width: 40ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}69.29824561403508% { width: 40ch; margin-left: -28ch;}69.30824561403509% { width: 39ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}70.17543859649122% { width: 39ch; margin-left: -28ch;}70.18543859649122% { width: 38ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}71.05263157894737% { width: 38ch; margin-left: -28ch;}71.06263157894738% { width: 37ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}71.9298245614035% { width: 37ch; margin-left: -28ch;}71.93982456140351% { width: 36ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}72.80701754385964% { width: 36ch; margin-left: -28ch;}72.81701754385965% { width: 35ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}73.68421052631578% { width: 35ch; margin-left: -28ch;}73.69421052631579% { width: 34ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}74.56140350877193% { width: 34ch; margin-left: -28ch;}74.57140350877194% { width: 33ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}75.43859649122807% { width: 33ch; margin-left: -28ch;}75.44859649122807% { width: 32ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}76.3157894736842% { width: 32ch; margin-left: -28ch;}76.32578947368421% { width: 31ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}77.19298245614034% { width: 31ch; margin-left: -28ch;}77.20298245614035% { width: 30ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}78.0701754385965% { width: 30ch; margin-left: -28ch;}78.0801754385965% { width: 29ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}78.94736842105263% { width: 29ch; margin-left: -28ch;}78.95736842105264% { width: 28ch; margin-left: -28ch; opacity: 1;}79.82456140350877% { width: 28ch; margin-left: -28ch;}79.83456140350877% { width: 45ch; margin-left: -46ch; opacity: 1;}80.7017543859649% { width: 46ch; opacity: 1;}80.71175438596491% { width: 47ch; opacity: 1;}81.57894736842105% { width: 47ch; opacity: 1;}81.58894736842106% { width: 48ch; opacity: 1;}82.45614035087719% { width: 48ch; opacity: 1;}82.4661403508772% { width: 49ch; opacity: 1;}83.33333333333333% { width: 49ch; opacity: 1;}83.34333333333333% { width: 50ch; opacity: 1;}84.21052631578947% { width: 50ch; opacity: 1;}84.22052631578947% { width: 51ch; opacity: 1;}85.0877192982456% { width: 51ch; opacity: 1;}85.09771929824561% { width: 52ch; opacity: 1;}85.96491228070175% { width: 52ch; opacity: 1;}85.97491228070176% { width: 53ch; opacity: 1;}86.84210526315789% { width: 53ch; opacity: 1;}86.8521052631579% { width: 54ch; opacity: 1;}87.71929824561403% { width: 54ch; opacity: 1;}87.72929824561403% { width: 55ch; opacity: 1;}88.59649122807016% { width: 55ch; opacity: 1;}88.60649122807017% { width: 56ch; opacity: 1;}89.47368421052632% { width: 56ch; opacity: 1;}89.48368421052632% { width: 56ch; opacity: 1;}90.35087719298245% { width: 56ch; margin-left: -46ch;}90.36087719298246% { width: 55ch; margin-left: -46ch; opacity: 1;}91.22807017543859% { width: 55ch; margin-left: -46ch;}91.2380701754386% { width: 54ch; margin-left: -46ch; opacity: 1;}92.10526315789473% { width: 54ch; margin-left: -46ch;}92.11526315789473% { width: 53ch; margin-left: -46ch; opacity: 1;}92.98245614035088% { width: 53ch; margin-left: -46ch;}92.99245614035088% { width: 52ch; margin-left: -46ch; opacity: 1;}93.85964912280701% { width: 52ch; margin-left: -46ch;}93.86964912280702% { width: 51ch; margin-left: -46ch; opacity: 1;}94.73684210526315% { width: 51ch; margin-left: -46ch;}94.74684210526316% { width: 50ch; margin-left: -46ch; opacity: 1;}95.61403508771929% { width: 50ch; margin-left: -46ch;}95.62403508771929% { width: 49ch; margin-left: -46ch; opacity: 1;}96.49122807017544% { width: 49ch; margin-left: -46ch;}96.50122807017544% { width: 48ch; margin-left: -46ch; opacity: 1;}97.36842105263158% { width: 48ch; margin-left: -46ch;}97.37842105263158% { width: 47ch; margin-left: -46ch; opacity: 1;}98.24561403508771% { width: 47ch; margin-left: -46ch;}98.25561403508772% { width: 46ch; margin-left: -46ch; opacity: 1;}99.12280701754385% { width: 46ch; margin-left: -46ch;}99.13280701754385% { width: 0; margin-left: 0; display: none; opacity:0;}100% { width: 0; margin-left: 0; display: none; opacity:0;}}</style></head>
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">TRANSFORM YOUR BRAND THROUGH<br>
  <div class="typewriterinner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Animation of CSS property "content" works everywhere except Safari. You'll have to use JavaScript for this kind of things.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/#browser-support